# How to update(visually) a polymer element containing data from a url that changes?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I´m trying to display a polymer element with some info. This element is generated when I tap an icon. As firstly it has no data, is not displayed but neither when the data is loaded. It looks like the visual part is not updated. I've been seeking for a solution checking the polymer manuel and this post but couldnt make it work. Has it something to do with ready function??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you got the problem 
          `<post-service id="service" sondas="{{sondas}}"></post-service>` 
onwards try putting `posts="{{sondas}}"`, Its an attribute you can't create attributes on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this part works. the problem is that when I change one of the variables into the hidden condition it doesnt affect the element view that has changed.

Comment: but i suggest you to use bootstrap and jquery for any development purpose, as polymer is in beta version yet